# Getting Python to output data to Excel Sheet

Tags: python

I am trying to output prices given by an API for each stock symbol, into an excel sheet. The code works to output the data into the command line, but once I tried putting it into a sheet, the code gives back this error, 
`File "C:\Users\sss\Documents\Python Programs\Bot\Td\td3.py", line 42, in get_ohlc 
 for symbol, lastPrice in kwargs.get('symbol'): 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I am not sure where to go from this point. The relevant code is below, and any help would be greatly appreciated !

```
data_sheet1 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\sss\\Downloads\\companylist.xlsx', index_col=0)
data_impor = data_sheet1.head(2600)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('c:\\Users\\sss\\Downloads\\output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Stock')
worksheet.write('B1', 'Price')

row = 1
col = 0

def get_ohlc(**kwargs):
    data = get_quotes(symbol=kwargs.get('symbol'))
    for symbol in kwargs.get('symbol'):
        print(symbol)
        print(data[symbol]['lastPrice'])
    for symbol, lastPrice in kwargs.get('symbol'): 
        worksheet.write(row, col, symbol) 
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, lastPrice) 
        row += 1
    workbook.close()


for row in data_impor.index:
    get_ohlc(symbol=[row])
```

Comment: In one line you expect `symbol` to be stored in `kwargs['symbol']` but in the second `for` loop within `get_ohlc` you expect 'symbol` and `lastPrice` to be stored in `kwargs['symbol']`. Which one is it? Did you mean to reference a different key of the `kwargs` dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to iterate through multiple columns in parallel. I'm not sure of everything that your code does, but here is an example:

Try

```
for symbol, lastPrice in zip(kwargs.get('symbol'), kwargs.get('lastPrice')):
```

Or

```
for symbol, lastPrice in zip(data['symbol'],data['lastPrice']):
```

The existing code `for symbol, lastPrice in kwargs.get('symbol'):` is the source of this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

You have only provided one column but two iterators, so it can't iterate unless you zip another column in or use a different method. Zip is my favorite and easiest for this problem though in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you. It is giving me this error now, ` File "C:\Users\nhaup\Documents\Python Programs\Bot\Td\td3.py", line 42, in get_ohlc
    for symbol, lastPrice in zip(kwargs.get('symbol'), kwargs.get('lastPrice')): 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable ` I believe my syntax somewhere else may be causing this error. But thank you for fixing the other one!

Comment: This is how I usually through two columns in parallel of a dataframe called `data`. The code is: `for symbol, lastPrice in zip(data['symbol'],data['lastPrice']):` I'm not sure what your code is doing with kwargs and .get(), but the code I just posted is fundamentally how you would do it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-iterate-multiple-lists-simultaneously/  This article shows lists, but it is pretty much the exact same thing for dataframe columns